# angular 2 - child @Input property not defined when using nested @Input() properties in nested components

Tags: angular, data-binding, nested, angular2-components, angular-decorator

Trying to make my app more modular, so i am creating nested components as follows:

This is a dropdown component which is reused multiple time in charts-page component.

**Dropdown.component.ts**

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['dropdown.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})

/**
 * @classdesc Dropdown component class
 */
export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit {


  private opened: boolean = false;

  /**
   * placeholder for the dropdown
   * @type {string}
   */
  @Input() placeholder: string;

  /**
   * event handler which is called when selected value is changed
   * @type {EventEmitter<any>}
   */
  @Output() onSelect = new EventEmitter<any>();

  /**
   * inner select component component
   */
  // @ViewChild('select') selectComponent: any;

  /**
   * Two way data binding implementation for selectedValue property
   */
  @Output() selectedChange: EventEmitter<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.selectedChange = new EventEmitter();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  /**
   * selectedValue setter. if value is not a string we are "Stringifying it"
   * @param value - the selected value
   */
  @Input() selected: { label: string, value: string };

  /**
   * options setter. if object "value" property is not a string we are "Stringifying it"
   * @param value
   */
  @Input() options;
    ....
    }
```

This is the charts page which has several instances of my dropdowns (only showing one to make it simple)

**Charts-Page.html**

```html
...
<div class="content">
   <my-dropdown [options]="timeframeDropdownInfo.options" 
       [placeholder]="timeframeDropdownInfo.placeholder" 
       [(selected)]="timeframeDropdownInfo.selectedOption"
       (onSelect)="timeframeDropdownInfo.onSelect($event)">
   </my-dropdown>
</div>...
```

**Charts-Page.ts**

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'charts-page',
  templateUrl: './charts-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./charts-page.component.css'],
})
export class ChartsPageComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() timeframeDropdownInfo: DropdownModel;
  ...


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

now, i want to reuse charts page component in several places with different data. like this:

**Trades-Component.html**

```ts
<charts-page [timeframeDropdownInfo]="timeframeDropdownInfo"></charts-page>
```

and this is how i initialize my timeframeDropdownInfo property:

**Trades.Component.ts**

```ts
    ...
  constructor(private tradeService: TradeService, private myElement: ElementRef) {

        //timeframe dropdown
        this.timeframeDropdownInfo = new DropdownModel();
        this.timeframeDropdownInfo.options = TransactionsTradesData.TIME_FRAMES;
        this.timeframeDropdownInfo.placeholder = 'Time Frame';
        this.timeframeDropdownInfo.selectedOption = this.selectedTimeframe;
        this.timeframeDropdownInfo.onSelect = this.onTimeframeChange;
...
```

Problem is that the dropdown is empty. the problem is not with the dropdown cause it worked before. only when i added one more level of nesting the binding broke.
Using Augury shows everything is initialized on chart-page level, but within dropdown component properties are not defined. so my guess is that dropdown is rendered before data is initiated, but i thought @Input annotation would work this out.
any ideas how can i make this multi-level nesting work?

Comment: update your charts component

Comment: I can elaborate but I need to try out few options, coz I faced this long back. are you available in team viewer

Comment: can you update the charts component code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139682/discussion-between-ori-price-and-aravind).